# selenium webdriver - fill up a table

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have a table (7 columns x 6 lines), where 7th column is total of cells 1-6 in each line.

I have to fill up whole table, I simply use sequence: driver.findElement..., element.click();element.sendKeys("strictly numeric value");

The problem is, sometimes (cca 1/3 runs) the cells in column Total are not correct calculated (or event not at all). **When filling up the table manualy, all totals are correct**. The total is calculated after some value is entered in cells 1 to 6 and any click is made. I added a extra click after entering sixth value in each line, but without success.

I also tried explicit wait to expected condition on the total cells, errs persists after timeout. Even Thread.sleep(1000); after entering sixth value in line did not solve the problem. Any idea, how to fill up the table and get correct totals? thanks

Comment: What is the value you are getting? Is the value 0? Or is it missing one of the 6 filled in values in its total?

Comment: Sometimes 0, sometimes it is missing some of the 6 values. All the six values are entered properly in 100% of runs.

Comment: The error rate is significantly smaller, when no other browser window is opened. At this time I added Thread.sleep(100); after enetering value in each cell and it seems to be OK. But I have more tables (even bigger) and pile of sleeps disproportionately increases duration of the tests. There must be a more elegant way.

Comment: 100ms is not sufficient, totals still bad :-/

Comment: Could you try sending a clear() first? Don't know if its the solution, but lets try some things :)

Comment: I clear the whole form in @After method, yet I'll try. At this moment, with clicking out of the table works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was little bit desperate and started from beginning. Than figured out I don't need to click to the cell to fill it up (didn't work before some changes was made in the html source code). So I reduced my code to this:

```
WebElement L3_C1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@class,'cell A1_Number_Of_Foos')]"));
L3_C1.sendKeys("3,00");
WebElement L3_C2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@class,'cell A2_Number_Of_Foos')]"));
L3_C2.sendKeys("3,00");
WebElement L3_C3 = ... etc.
```

Next I construct filling up all the cells:

```
String[] rowId_DaP = {A BUNCH OF XPATHS};
private WebElement FE_DaP(String rowId_DaP) {return driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@class,'rowId_DaP')]"));}
for (String rowId_DaP: rowId_DaP) {WebElement cell = FE_DaP(rowId_DaP);cell.sendKeys("3,00");
```

All totals are correct in 100% runs and the tests are even faster.

**A simple conclusion: DO NOT perform any action unless it is realy necessary.**